# How to make 'touchesBegan' method work for a specific view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, touchesbegan

In my add contact page, i have a view and a scrollview on it and again a view on it. and in that last view i ve textboxes, etc. i have given the 'touchesBegan' method but it is called only for the view at the bottom. how to point that method to another view i.e., the view at the top?

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 [self.AddView endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way this is how you can do :

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == image1)
    {
        //Action
    }

}
```

**Please Note :** As you are using UIScrollView you might not able to get touches method for UIScrollView. In that case you might have to use UIGesture.

Comment: thumbs up for mentioning it won't work with `UIScrollView` :)

Comment: Yes, this is like going one step deeper to the problem :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the answer in Swift:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    if(touch.view == myView){
        // Code
    }
}
```

Comment: what does mean `touches.first`

Comment: @iOSDeveloper It is where the user first started touching the screen. There could be multiple of these touch events as the user could be dragging their finger on the screen. The last one would be touches.last.

Answer (score 6):

First check the property `UserInteractionEnabled` of that whole controls and set to `YES`

After check out your bottom view frame that its not over on that views

And after you can checkout that with bellow condition and do something with particular controls touch event..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [touch locationInView:viewBoard];
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
       UIImageView *tempImage=(UIImageView *) touch.view;
       if (tempImage.tag  == yourImageTag) 
       {
          /// write your code here
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
  - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch1 = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch1 locationInView:self.finalScore];

         if(CGRectContainsPoint(YourView.frame, touchLocation));
         {
            //Do stuff.
         }


  }
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:vTouch] anyObject];
    if(!touch)
        return;

    CGPoint pointNow = [touch locationInView:otherView];
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your view is a parent view then can use this code:

```
if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: yourView)


        let pnt: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y)

        if (yourView.bounds.contains(pnt)) {
           //You can use: yourView.frame.contains(pnt)


            //OK.


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Referring to the Apple documentation on UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder), all UIView objects (which includes UIWindow), UIApplication object, UIViewController objects are all instances of UIResponder. To handle a specific type of event, a responder must override the corresponding methods.

In our case `touches` is our type of event. So our responder should implement the following methods.
touchesBegan(*:with:), touchesMoved(*:with:), touchesEnded(*:with:), and touchesCancelled(*:with:)

Since we only wish to know when a user has touched a particular view, we only need to implement `touchesBegan(_:with:)`. Since we are not overriding the other methods we must call `super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)`. If we were overriding **ALL** of the other methods, we wouldn't be required to call `super`.

Looking at [`touchesBegan(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) the parameter `touches` is a set of UITouch instances. Each instance represents the touches for the starting phase of the event, which is represented by the parameter `event`.

For touches in a view, this set contains only one touch by default. Hence `touches.first` is the only UITouch instance in the set. We then access the property `view`, this represents the view or window in which the touch occurred. Lastly we compare the view that has been touched with your desired view.

It should be noted that if you wish to receive multiple touches- you must set the view's `isMultipleTouchEnabled` property to `true`. Then the set of `touches` will have more than one UITouch instance and you will have to handle that accordingly.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        if let touch = touches.first, touch.view == myView {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @DangNguyen thanks for the suggestion. I've gone ahead and given a more detailed answer.